# Microsoft dynamics crm - upload files?

Tags: file, microsoft-dynamics

I am new to Microsoft CRM. Is there an option to upload attachment to an entity (e.g. Opportunity) to Notes & Attachments section like in Salesforce ?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 or Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015, you can upload attachments to notes.  It might not be readily apparent as the Attach button in the Note field doesn't show up until you click into the note field title or body area.  For the default forms, the Notes on an Opportunity form will be in what's called the Social pane in the middle of the form, composed of "Posts", "Activities", and "Notes".  Simply click on the Notes to see existing notes or to add new notes and attachments.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334398.aspx - "Annotation (note) entity" for more detail on notes and attachments.

Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and earlier also allows for uploading attachments to records as well and is similar, but has slightly different navigation for adding them since those versions don't have the Social pane.  See this blog post for more detail about the social pane - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2013/10/30/new-customization-capabilities-of-social-pane.aspx